# Proc SQL: CASE WHEN nested

Tags: sql, nested, sas, case, proc-sql

Using nested case in Proc sql, I need to get the value of a column based on the specified year and month. For eg - If the year is 2018 and the month is december then it should return the value of the column x201811 and if it is null it should return zero. The code which I have written below is giving a syntax error. Please suggest a solution.

```
CASE  WHEN (( Year(date) = 2018 ) AND ( Month(date) = 12 )) THEN x201811 
     WHEN x201811 IS NULL THEN 0
   ELSE x201811
   WHEN ((Year(date)=2018) AND (Month(Date)=11)) THEN x201810
    WHEN x201810 IS NULL THEN 0
   ELSE x201810
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COALESCE` function to cause the first non-null value to become the assigned value.

```
CASE
  WHEN (( Year(date) = 2018 ) AND ( Month(date) = 12 )) 
  THEN coalesce (x201811, 0)

  WHEN ((Year(date)=2018) AND (Month(Date)=11)) 
  THEN coalesce (x201810, 0)

  ELSE coalesce (x201810, 0)
END as got_a_value
```

The alternative would be to nest `CASE` statements

```
CASE
  WHEN (( Year(date) = 2018 ) AND ( Month(date) = 12 )) 
  THEN CASE WHEN x201811 is null then 0 else x201811 end

  WHEN ((Year(date)=2018) AND (Month(Date)=11))
  THEN CASE WHEN x201810 is null then 0 else x201810 end

  ELSE ...
END as got_a_value
```